# In firefox and IE getTime method not working with date in string format like "25-Mar-2015"

Tags: angularjs

In firefox and IE getTime method not working with date in string format like "25-Mar-2015"

but it works in chrome opera and safari

i also tried using $filter

Comment: can you show your code

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on formats recognized by javascript Date constructor (read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse) for more details). Formats that are recognized are browser dependent.

Either parse the date yourself and use the constructor that gets day, month and year as different arguments or use some library, e.g. [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/).

```
var date = moment(yourString, "DD-MMM-YYYY").toDate();
date.getTime();
```